# PayPal payment method not working properly

Tags: html, http, shopping-cart, paypal

I am redirecting users to PayPal's payment site by using this HTTP Location header. It is all in one line but I have broken it down for readability. Unfortunately, the fields in bold are not sent to PayPal's website. (The last one (email) is sent.) Anybody know why ?

Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?
amount_1=100&
item_name_1=ProductName&
upload=1&
business=myemail%40mydomain.com&
cmd=_cart&
currency_code=USD&
item_number_1=12345&
country=US&
first_name=x&
last_name=x&
**address1=x&**
**address2=x&**
**zip=x&**
**city=x&**
email=x@domain.com&
\n\n

[PayPal's Instructions Site](https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_std-variable-ref-cart-upload.html)

Comment: Is the address, and are the other fields for that matter, URL encoded?

Answer (score 0):

It said `"address1 - Street (1 of 2 fields) - Alphanumeric - Limit 100"`
Did you input more than `100` characters?
And make sure you entered a `[SPACE]` as `%20` (URIencode).